# Nested interpolation in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I have a messages.properties file that contains some text used to replace variables inside a template. Suppose my template has the following:

```
<tr>
  <td class="green">${message_in_green}</td>
</tr>
```

My message.properties then has:

```
message_in_green=Click <a href="${back_link}">here</a> to go back.
```

In my Java code, I have created a Map that stores the `back_link` (among other things... which I can reference directly in the template using interpolation):

```
data.put("back_link", "http://blah.com");
```

The end result is `back_link` is not replaced with `http://blah.com`, which I somewhat expected. Can I make nested interpolation like the above in Freemarker (where the template references a string of text in a properties file, and the string of text references something that was set in Java code)? If so, what is the proper way of replacing `back_link`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<td class="green"><@message_in_green?interpret /></td>
```

where `message_in_green?interpret` interprets `message_in_green` as a template, and returns a directive that executes that template, and you call a directive with `<@... />`. As it's a template, it could also contain `#if`, `#list`, etc.

Comment: Of course! One of the things I tried was a directive, but I had it in the properties file instead. Thinking about it again, this makes perfect sense. Thank you.